# AC vs DC refrigerator

Tags: ac, dc, inverter

I’m looking to purchase a refrigerator for my van.  I plan to have an inverter installed and a battery bank.  AC refrigerators are much cheaper than DC so I prefer to go that route if possible.  The AC refrigerator has a power drawl of roughly 300KWA per year while the DC refrigerator drawls roughly 48W.  The battery bank I’m planning is 200A at 12V and the inverter is 3000VA.  Can you tell me if I can get away with the AC refrigerator and how much, if any loss I’ll be dealing with?

Comment: If the DC refrigerator runs on thermoelectrics, it is likely much less efficient.  Running a large load through an inverter is also bad as even with a 90% efficient inverter you'd waste a ton of power.  In addition to that, some inverters are much less efficient at small loads than rated loads, but you need an oversized inverter to deal with the surge current when the compressor starts.  This means you might end up significantly below 90% efficiency, so at the least it's a component selection problem.  Do you mean 300kWh rather than 300KWA?

Comment: 48W all day every day works out to 420.48 kWh/year, so significantly more power than the AC fridge.  There's no reason a DC compressor can't be efficient, so you might want to check some other fridges.  Insulation is a factor as well as the power consumed to maintain a temperature is determined by the difference between that temperature and ambient and the quality of the insulation.

Comment: it's `power draw` ... drawl is texas accent ... lol

Comment: *"300KWA"* = 300 kelvin watt amps. If you mean kilowatts then it's kW.

Comment: @KH 48W will be power consumption while running; it probably won't be 420kWh/year unless the fridge door is propped open...

Comment: @BrianDrummond for a fridge would they not spec by average consumption?  The figure seems reasonable for either a thermoelectric device or a slightly more powerful compressor fridge.

Comment: @KH DC fridges tend to be based on a specific compressor which draws about 4A  ( https://assets.danfoss.com/documents/107889/AI017486436109en-000101.pdf ) or clones, and you have to factor in the duty cycle according to implementation details like insulation : the OP will have to figure that out from the datasheets they haven't linked. Note : it wouldn't make sense for an appliance designed for low power roles to draw more overall than a common or garden (much cheaper) AC one.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  K.H. I believe you’re correct, it should be KWH.  The fridge I’m considering stated 300KWH per year.  My bad.  Jsotola, lol.  I’m not from the south, haha.  Misspelled.  Brian, I believe you’re correct.  The power noted is 48W on the average while running.  How does that convert to annual consumption?  So I can compare it to the AC power consumption.  Also, thank you for the spec sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information in your post to provide a good recommendation.  However, I can make some recommendations as follows: a) you want to optimize power efficiency, so choose a refrigerator that is just as large as you need  b) the DC refrigerator is indeed a thermoelectric-based system that is extremely inefficient and should be avoided  c) you should be able to find DC, compressor-based (refrigerant) refrigerators - this is a good option  d) also consider a propane refrigerator.